# Is the output of GRU in Pytorch just the hidden states?

Tags: pytorch

I understand how GRU works, but now I'm confused by the difference between "hidden" and "output" of GRU in Pytorch: is "output" just the hidden states of the GRU, or the hidden states after some transformations? If "output" is just the hidden states, why do we want both `output` and `h_n` as return value of `GRU.forward`, since we can just get `h_n` from the last element of `output`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html):

- **output** is a tensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, num_layers, num_directions * hidden_size​)
- **h_n** a tensor of shape (num_directions * num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)

The first provides you with hidden states *across the entire sequence*, allowing you to use intermediate representations (e.g. for attention) or train for step-separable tasks (e.g. token-level classification).
The latter provides you with just *a single summary vector* per input sequence, which is handy if you're only interested in a sequence-level representation that doesn't involve token-wise attention.

There is **no** implicit hidden-to-output transformation.

Comment: thanks, I verified that indeed the last element of output[0] is the same as output[1].